# Link cwd of vim with parent shell

Tags: neovim, tmux

Is it possible to link the cwd of vim to the cwd of the shell running it, or change the cwd of the parent shell within vim?

I run neovim+tmux with the tmux-resurrect plugin, and it would be nice if I could restore the neovim session associated with the cwd of all the saved tmux session panes/windows upon executing the resurrect restore command. However, the cwd of the shell running neovim is separate from the cwd of the neovim instance. I would like to create an autocommand that triggers on the event `DirChanged` to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how or if it's even possible to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: In general child processes can't affect parent processes like that (change working directory or environment variables, etc.) - not without the cooperation of the parent process anyway. So, e.g., you could have neovim write the current directory to some file and configure the shell to change to to whichever directory is listed in that file.

Comment: On a `Linux` box, you can usually query the `proc` pseudo-filesystem (commonly mounted at `/proc`) about process-related information. For example, you can _try_ to change `cwd` _to_ the parent process's `cwd` in `Vim` as follows: (1) `:let b:ppid = split(readfile('/proc/self/stat', '', 1)[0])[3]`, (2) `:exec 'lcd /proc/'. b:ppid .'/cwd'`. See the manual page of `proc`(5).